# Using NSMutableArray for UITableviewcell

Tags: uitableview, ios6, nsmutablearray, uitextfield

I am trying to use an NSMutableArray to build my tableview's datasource. The NSMutableArray is empty.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    return [self.ingredientsArray count];

}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    // Configure the cell...
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [self.ingredientsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
```

I have a 'Add' button so users enter their ingredients in a textfield and this is added to the array. There is nothing wrong with the array getting loaded. There is something wrong with the     cell.textLabel.text = [self.ingredientsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; But I cannot put my finger on it. I have look on the site and seen a couple of answers to similar questions but they do not seem to work. I have tried changing the numbersinrow: method to a value and the app doesn't compile.

I then added an object to the NSMutablearray in view did load. Changed the numberOfRowsinSection: method to 1 and in the cellForRowAtIndexPath: kept that the same and I was able to see the test String that I put in. However this is not what I am going for.

I want a user to enter a string (ingredient) in the text field and for this to be displayed in the tableview underneath. Now when I add strings to the NSMutableArray they are not displayed in the tableview just the one test string is present. They are getting added correctly as I have nslog'd it to check.

Any help or advice is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried calling insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:?

Answer (score 0):

There's the following common mistakes done by newbies with `NSMutableArray` and `UITableView`

For the below points if you should say YES,

1) You've connected `UITableView` delegate and datasource? i.e. `tableView.delegate = self;` and `tableView.datasource = self;`

2) Your `NSMutableArray` is allocated before adding objects in it.

3) Can you print (NSLog) the added objects from `NSMutableArray`. i.e. `NSLog(@"Count %d",[array count]);`

4) Are you reloading `UITableView` after adding object into `NSMutableArray`? i.e. `[tableview reloadData];`

5) Put the break points for `UITableView` datasource, are they call?

Comment: 1 - In - (UIImage *)cellBackgroundForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath. I have the line     NSInteger rowCount = [self tableView:[self tableView] numberOfRowsInSection:0];

Comment: 2 - Yes my nsmutablearray is alloc init'd before use. 3- I can print the array and the count is as expected.

Comment: 4) I am not reloading tableview. 5) They are called. From my question you can see I can see the output if I make the above changes (load array, change number of rows to 1 etc).

Comment: Okay, it would be good if you can update your question with the code you're doing for adding ingredients into array. Not sure, but there may be some problem in adding.

Comment: There is an 'Add' button with a corresponding method. I alloc init' in the view did load. Then use addObject method. Then print the array and log the count. It is important to note that this works correctly as expected. Do you have any ideas as to how I should attack the problem. For your point 1 I have shown you the code. As in should I not be connecting to self.

Comment: @Anthony, are you allocating array with setting capacity? it should be something like, `arrayObject = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];`

Comment: Yes that is the case. I do that in the viewDidLoad method. The actual adding of the ingredients happens in the 'Add' method.

Comment: Okay, in your `Add` action, do check for allocating of array, something like `if(!array) {arrayObject = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];}` I think it may lost its address so you can't add the data into array.

Comment: Are you sure that is the issue. I haven't tried it yet but I will. My alloc init is currently in the view did load. So isn't this called first so my array is always initialized?

Comment: Yes @Anthony, you're right, but your array may looses it address from memory I guess, that's why!

Comment: Hi Hemang - Many thanks! The simulator now loads up. But I can not see the contents in the tableview cells. Everything is getting added to my array that I add in the textfield. I can see the nslog's in xcode. Do you have any idea why I can't see anything i.e. why it is not displayed?

Comment: Oh, that's sad! Without checking the code now, I can't say anything! -- We tried with almost the things.

Comment: I needed [[self tableview]reloadData] in the add method. Works great now! Thanks for your help it was really appreciated.

Comment: @Anthony, oh damn!! but good! finally! I've already pointed this in my  answer in 4th point. :)